# How to convert NoneType value from aggregate to float in Python?

Tags: python, django, aggregate-functions, type-conversion

I have a Django **models.py** file with a class defined as follows:

```
class Cotizacion(models.Model):
    # Fields
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = extension_fields.AutoSlugField(populate_from='nombre', blank=True)
    fecha_vence = models.DateField(default=now)
    _subtotal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,
                                    decimal_places=2,
                                    null=True,
                                    blank=True,
                                    db_column='subtotal',
                                    default=0)
    _total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,
                                 decimal_places=2,
                                 null=True,
                                 blank=True,
                                 db_column='total',
                                 default=0)
    _utilidad = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,
                                    decimal_places=6,
                                    null=True,
                                    blank=True,
                                    db_column='utilidad',
                                    default=0)
    # utilidad = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    # total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    actualizado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

    # Relationship Fields
    itinerario = models.ForeignKey(Itinerario, on_delete=CASCADE, verbose_name='itinerario')
    nivel_de_precio = models.ForeignKey(NivelDePrecio,
                                        verbose_name='nivel de precio',
                                        on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-id',)
        verbose_name = _('Cotización')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Cotizaciones')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.nombre

    @property
    def subtotal(self):
        agregado = self.lineas.aggregate(subtotal=Sum('monto'))
        return agregado['subtotal']

    @subtotal.setter
    def subtotal(self, value):
        self._subtotal = value

    @property
    def total(self):
        agregado = self.lineas.aggregate(total=Sum('total'))
        return format(math.ceil(agregado['total'] / redondeoLps) * redondeoLps, '.2f')
        # return math.ceil(agregado['total'] / redondeoLps) * redondeoLps

    @total.setter
    def total(self, value):
        self._total = value

    @property
    def utilidad(self):
        agregado1 = self.lineas.aggregate(costo=Sum('monto'))
        agregado2 = self.lineas.aggregate(precio=Sum('total'))
        precio = agregado2['precio']
        precioRnd = math.ceil(precio / redondeoLps) * redondeoLps
        if agregado2['precio'] == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            ganancia = round((precioRnd - agregado1['costo']) / precioRnd, 4)
            return ganancia

    @utilidad.setter
    def utilidad(self, value):
        self._utilidad = value

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('transporte_cotizacion_detail', args=(self.slug,))

    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('transporte_cotizacion_update', args=(self.slug,))
```

Aggregate values used in **_subtotal**, **_total**, and **_utilidad** fields come from a related class (**CotizacionDetalle**) which is a child from this class, as in a **Master --> Detail** relationship, being **Cotizacion** the Header table, and **CotizacionDetalle** the Lines table.

When run from my front end I get no errors and values are presented as I need them, as shown in the following image:

[note the 'Precio' value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeCyo.png)

...but when running the Django admin interface I get the following error message:

TypeError at /admin/transporte/cotizacion/

unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://demo.mistenants.com:8000/admin/transporte/cotizacion/
Django Version:     1.9.7
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Exception Location:

```
C:\Users\adalb\PycharmProjects\tenant\transporte\models.py in utilidad, line 330
```

Line 330 is this one:

```
precioRnd = math.ceil(precio / redondeoLps) * redondeoLps
```

**redondeoLps** is an int type variable with value of 50 (from an external parameters API)

The wierd thing is that I only get the error when accessed via the Django admin interfase.  Do the Django admin templates have a more strict evaluation of datatypes?  How can I perform operations with variables from aggregate functions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow SE.  Be sure to take the tour at https://stackoverflow.stackexchange.com/Tour

Comment: @abijith-mg Thanks, more readable indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce
self.lineas.aggregate(precio=Coalesce(Sum('total'), 0))
```

**OR**

```
precioRnd = math.ceil((precio or 0) / (redondeoLps or 0)) * redondeoLps
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution.

Comment: Although the first option solved the problem, the second only replaced the result with 0